# How can I handle the error in load_svmlight_file?

Tags: macos, syntax, svmlight

when I run this code in mac:

```
x_train, y_train = load_svmlight_file("mq2008.train")
```

I get this error in bash:

```sh
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

and if I run it in shell, I face this error:

```
NameError: name 'load_svmlight_file' is not defined
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

IMO, you have a Python code and trying to replicate its output. If so, you should first load all Python-related imports first. This is what it means to `NameError` here, Python interpreter is not able to understand what it is, because this function is not part of its existing definitions it has.

If I may suggest, please spend some time to get the hands-on-learning of Python.

Comment: Would you tell me for this especial code what kind of imports should I load?

Comment: Sure! You need to import `load_svmlight_file ` function.

Comment: Example of how you import `from os import path`; Here `os` is a python internal library and `path` can be package/function/variable you are importing.